# How do I translate 'no philosopher student admires any rotten lecturer' into quantificational logic formula?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

Let's assume that $Fx=x$ is a philosophy student, $Rx=x$ is a rotten lecturer, and $Mxy=x$ admires $y$.

My translation of the sentence was $\forall x(Fx\supset\neg\forall y(Ry\supset Mxy))$, but my logic textbook translated it as $\neg\exists x(Fx\wedge\exists y(Ry\wedge Mxy))$.

As far as I know, `no philosophy student admires any rotten lecturer` means the same as `every philosophy student doesn't admire every rotten lecturer`. But, the textbook's author seems to understand it as `every philosophy student doesn't admire some rotten lecturer`. How do I wrap my mind around this?

Comment: Are you sure your translation is not "logically equivalent" to the textbook's?

Comment: @GEdgar They are not equivalent.

Comment: You are using set operators where logical operators would be more correct.

Comment: @QthePlatypus My logic textbook uses it to mean material implication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trip-up is that the usage of "any" *when inside a negated clause* refers to "some" rather than "every".

Hence "No F admires any R" translates as "there does not exists an F that admires an R."

$$\neg\exists x~\Big(F(x) \wedge \exists y~\big(R(y)\wedge M(x,y)\big)\Big)$$

Which is equivalent to $$\forall x~\Big(F(x)\to ~\forall y~\big(R(y)\big)\to \neg M(x,y)\big)\Big)$$

Or in PNF: $$\forall x~\forall y~\Big(\big(F(x)\wedge R(y)\big) \to \neg M(x,y)\Big)$$

Answer (score 0):

I realized that `no philosophy student admires every rotten lecturer` cannot possibly mean the same thing as `no philosopher student admires any rotten lecturer`. It is the same thing as `no philosopher student admires some rotten lecturer`.